# Show that the set $B:= \left \{ (a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \right \}$ is a basis...

Tags: general-topology

Show that the set $B:= \left \{ (a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \right \}$ is a basis for some topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but that this topology is strictly coarser than the upper limit topology $\mathcal{T}_{u}$

If anyone could provide a detailed explanation for this exercise (from Topology 2nd Ed, by Munkres), that would help me immensely. I've been going through the problem section and this is one of the few problems that has really confused me.

Answer (score 1):

You should know the conditions for some collection of sets to be a base. Then you should test whether the conditions hold for your concrete set.

For the upper limit topology, note that its basis allows real endpoints of the intervals while here we allow only rational endpoints.

So what part do you have a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the intersection of two elements of $B$ : $(a_1,b_1]\cap{}(a_2,b_2]$ is either empty or a set $(c,d] \in{}B$. The other conditions for basis is trivial.

Now consider the set $U=(0,\sqrt{2}]$, which is open in upper limit topology. But $U$ cannot be open in the topology generated by the basis $B$, since $\sqrt{2}\in{U}$ has no basic neighborhood contained in $U$.